# Matlab to C++ percentile clipping

Tags: c++, performance, matlab

I have a 2D matrix in Matlab and I want to convert the Matlab code into C++.

In C++ I have `int* channel_gr`. The commented code is the original Matlab code.

Is there a faster way to execute this code?

```
//Gr(1:ROIY(1), :)      = clipLevel;
for (int i = 0; i < _roiY1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < newWidth; j++)
    {
        channel_gr[i*newWidth + j] = clipLevel;
    }
}

//Gr(ROIY(2)+1:end, :)  = clipLevel;
for (int i = _roiY2-1; i < newHeight; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < newWidth; j++)
    {
        channel_gr[i*newWidth + j] = clipLevel;
    }
}

//Gr(:, 1:ROIX(1))      = clipLevel;
for (int i = 0; i < newHeight; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < _roiX1; j++)
    {
        channel_gr[i*newWidth + j] = clipLevel;
    }
}
//Gr(:, ROIX(2)+1:end)  = clipLevel;
for (int i = 0; i < newHeight; i++)
{
    for (int j = _roiX2-1; j < newWidth; j++)
    {
        channel_gr[i*newWidth + j] = clipLevel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The block

```
for (int i = 0; i < _roiY1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < newWidth; j++)
    {
        channel_gr[i*newWidth + j] = clipLevel;
    }
}
```

can be made more concise by using `std::fill`.

```
std::fill(channel_gr, channel_gr+_roiY1*newWidth, cliplevel);
```

I won't vouch for better performance though.